# Unable to import file of another folder in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

[image: Screenshot of Error]

I'm unable to import class from file Views.py(location: another folder) in file urls.py

It is showing error No module named VisitorAPI.views
(seems like it is looking for file in same folder not in another folder)

Tried various solutions but nothing is working out!

Comment: Why the letter I in your folder name and your code different?

Comment: They are same. Just a #fontstyle thing!

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because your VisitorAPI package is not recognized as a package. Add a `__init__.py` file at the root, and that should do the trick.

You can also add `VisitorAPI` as sources root, by right clicking -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root. This way, you can import it as `API.views ...`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with `BASE_DIR`. When you write `VisitorAPI.API.views`, it's looking for that module relative to `BASE_DIR` path. Just try fixing that and provide the path relative to `BASE_DIR`.
The fix would be:

```
from views import RegisterAPI
```